# JSON -> csv creating header line and padding header if found empty field

Tags: json, csv, padding, jq, missing-data

I have a programme in bash that get JSONline files with several million of these object per line (See [source](http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_pscdata.html))

```
{
  "company_number": "09626947",
  "data": {
    "address": {
      "address_line_1": "Troak Close",
      "country": "England",
      "locality": "Christchurch",
      "postal_code": "BH23 3SR",
      "premises": "9",
      "region": "Dorset"
    },
    "country_of_residence": "United Kingdom",
    "date_of_birth": {
      "month": 11,
      "year": 1979
    },
    "etag": "7123fb76e4ad7ee7542da210a368baa4c89d5a06",
    "kind": "individual-person-with-significant-control",
    "links": {
      "self": "/company/09626947/persons-with-significant-control/individual/FFeqke7T3LvGvX6xmuGqi5SJXAk"
    },
    "name": "Ms Angela Lynette Miller",
    "name_elements": {
      "forename": "Angela",
      "middle_name": "Lynette",
      "surname": "Miller",
      "title": "Ms"
    },
    "nationality": "British",
    "natures_of_control": [
      "significant-influence-or-control"
    ],
    "notified_on": "2016-06-06"
  }
}
```

I have my JQ query that looks like this:

```
for file in psc_chunk_*; do
jq --slurp --raw-output 'def pad($n): range(0;$n) as $i | 
.[$i]; ([.[] | .data.natures_of_control | length] | max) as $mx |
.[] | 
select(.data) |
[.company_number, .data.kind, .data.address.address_line_1, .data.address.country, .data.address.locality, .data.address.postal_code, .data.address.premises, .data.identification.country_registered, .data.identification.legal_authority, .data.identification.legal_form, .data.identification.place_registered, .data.identification.registration_number, .data.ceased_on, .data.country_of_residence, "\(.data.date_of_birth.year)-\(.data.date_of_birth.month)", .data.etag, .data.links.self, .data.name, .data.name_elements.title, .data.name_elements.forename, .data.name_elements.middle_name, .data.name_elements.surname, .data.nationality, .data.notified_on, (.data.natures_of_control | pad($mx))] |
@csv' $file > $file.csv;
done
```

Which is probably hurting the eyes of many JQ pros  out there - it is not efficient in extracting key:value pairs and if the provider happens to change name of a key my code wouldn't work anymore.

Is there a way to just flatten all the json into a csv **keeping the keys as headers** - with the extra difficulty that **there is a list `natures_of_control` which has a varying number of entries** (for which i used the pad function to get a rectangular result).

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines, especially the "minimal" part. It's not clear to me how you want to handle the array-valued key.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion - I forgot to write in the body of the question that I actually wanted all keys to become cols! Which is what you assumed in your answer below - thanks a lot! I'm testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach based on programmatically determining the headers.  To illustrate it, we confine attention to a single object.

Since jq's `paths` builtin ignores paths to null, and since one of the requirements here is NOT to ignore such paths, we start by defining some filters that are analogous to `paths/0` and `paths/1`:

```
# Generate a stream of all paths, including paths to null
def allpaths:
  def conditional_recurse(f):  def r: ., (select(.!=null) | f | r); r;
  path(conditional_recurse(.[]?)) | select(length > 0);

def allpaths(filter):
  allpaths as $p | getpath($p) as $v | select($v | filter) | $p;
```

Next, we define a function for abbreviating long paths. You may wish to tailor this to your needs.

```
# Input: an array denoting a path; output: a string
def abbreviate: if .[-1]|type == "number" then "\(.[-2]):\(.[-1])" else "\(.[-1])" end;
```

Finally, we pull everything together for the single-object case by generating a row of headers, followed by a row of the corresponding values:

```
[allpaths(scalars)] as $p
| ($p | map(abbreviate) | @csv),
  ([getpath($p[])] | @csv)
```

### Output

For the JSON object in the question, the output produced by the above (using the -r command-line option) would be the following CSV:

```
"company_number","address_line_1","country","locality","postal_code","premises","region","country_of_residence","month","year","etag","kind","self","name","forename","middle_name","surname","title","nationality","natures_of_control:0","notified_on"
"09626947","Troak Close","England","Christchurch","BH23 3SR","9","Dorset","United Kingdom",11,1979,"7123fb76e4ad7ee7542da210a368baa4c89d5a06","individual-person-with-significant-control","/company/09626947/persons-with-significant-control/individual/FFeqke7T3LvGvX6xmuGqi5SJXAk","Ms Angela Lynette Miller","Angela","Lynette","Miller","Ms","British","significant-influence-or-control","2016-06-06"
```

Comment: Hi Peak! This works beautifully, and I also learnt a lot of JQ syntax while deciphering your solution - thanks! After trying on jqplay with one json object per line I realised that it creates a header line every other line. Is there a way to just get 1 header with as many cols unpacking `natures_of_control` as there are in the longest `natures_of_control` array - while leaving the extra fields blank in the lines which don't have as many entries in their `natures_of_control` array. Wow - this was complicated, sorry and ofc anything at this stage would be appreciated!! :)

Comment: Tytire Recubans - Please see "Handling a stream of isomorphic objects efficiently" elsewhere on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which handles arrays in the input JSON by converting them to "colon-separated values":

```
def atos: map(tostring) | join(":");
```

The same generic `allpaths` filters as used elsewhere on this page are also used:

```
# Generate a stream of all paths, including paths to null
def allpaths:
  def conditional_recurse(f):  def r: ., (select(.!=null) | f | r); r;
  path(conditional_recurse(.[]?)) | select(length > 0);

def allpaths(filter):
  allpaths as $p | getpath($p) as $v | select($v | filter) | $p;
```

Again for the single-object case, a solution can be obtained as follows:

```
walk( if type == "array" then atos else . end )
| [allpaths(scalars)] as $p
| ($p | map(last) | @csv),
  ([getpath($p[])] | @csv)
```

### Output

For the given input, the output would be:

```
"company_number","address_line_1","country","locality","postal_code","premises","region","country_of_residence","month","year","etag","kind","self","name","forename","middle_name","surname","title","nationality","natures_of_control","notified_on"
"09626947","Troak Close","England","Christchurch","BH23 3SR","9","Dorset","United Kingdom",11,1979,"7123fb76e4ad7ee7542da210a368baa4c89d5a06","individual-person-with-significant-control","/company/09626947/persons-with-significant-control/individual/FFeqke7T3LvGvX6xmuGqi5SJXAk","Ms Angela Lynette Miller","Angela","Lynette","Miller","Ms","British","significant-influence-or-control","2016-06-06"
```

### Caveat

The solution presented here is intended only for use when the arrays in the input are all scalar-valued.

### Handling a stream of isomorphic objects efficiently

In the following, the stream of objects is assumed to be isomorphic in the sense that the ordering of keys within a JSON object is irrelevant.

#### Infrastructure

The `allpaths` and `atos` infrastructure is as above and so won't be repeated here.

#### Helper functions

```
# input: an object
def paths:
  walk( if type == "array" then atos else . end )
  | [allpaths(scalars)] ;

# input: an array of paths
def headers:
  map(last) | @csv ; 

# input: an object
def row($paths):
  walk( if type == "array" then atos else . end )
  | [getpath($paths[])]
  | @csv ;
```

#### Processing the input stream

The following uses `input` to read the first object, and `inputs` to read the rest, so it is essential to invoke jq with the -n command-line option:

```
input as $first
| ($first|paths) as $paths
| ($paths | headers),
  ($first | row($paths)),
  (inputs | row($paths))
```

Comment: Hi @peak - I just finally read all i needed to read from the manual and the wiki to understand your solution and tried it. I just wanted to shout out how elegant and portable the final solution for isomorphic objects is. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @peak. I am trying to use your first answer to [this json object](https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/search-overview/OfficerSearch-resource.html) - I'd like to get the full names tho. For example, if i have a nested object `{"matches" : [ { "address_snippet" : ["integer"] } ] }` I'd like the key for the value `"integer"` to be `"matches_address_snippet"`.